# Hyper-V won't enable in Windows 8 Pro: "Virtualization support is disabled in the firmware"

Tags: windows, virtualization, hyper-v, windows-8

The checkbox to install Hyper-V in Windows 8 Pro is disabled.  Hovering over it reveals the message, `Hyper-V cannot be installed: Virtualization support is disabled in the firmware.`  There is a virtualization option in the UEFI settings that was previously disabled, but I enabled it, and then did a cold boot.  My processor seems to support the necessary virtualization features, according to [the Intel website](http://ark.intel.com/products/71458/Intel-Core-i7-3632QM-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_20-GHz-rPGA) (VT-x and SLAT).  Do I have any chance of getting around this?

Comment: Contact your hardware vendor.

Comment: That's always fun.  I'll do that tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few more cold boots seem to have fixed the problem.  I guess one cycle wasn't enough.

**Update:**

The setting seems to reset every time I install major updates/OS upgrades.  To fix it, I need to:

1. Change the setting on my laptop
2. Let it boot into Windows
3. Turn off the computer normally (cutting power breaks the process)
4. Unplug the laptop
5. Remove the battery
6. Wait about 30 seconds
7. Replace battery, plug in, turn on
8. Repeat 2-3 times until it works

Answer (score 12):

There are a few requirements that must be met to enable Hyper-V on Windows 8. According to [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857623.aspx), other than SLAT, you must also have 4GB of RAM and the system must be 64-bit. These requirements are listed on the [Client Hyper-V page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857623.aspx) on TechNet.

There is a simple check that you can also run to verify that your system meets the requirements. Open a command prompt and type ‘systeminfo.exe’ (without the quotes) and hit enter. The last section will show four lines:

VM Monitor Mode Extensions:

Virtualization Enabled in Firmware:

Second Level Address Translation:

Data Execution Prevention Available:

These will have either ‘Yes’ or ‘No’ next to them, which should help you to track down the exact issue that is stopping you from enabling Hyper-V on your system.

More information about Hyper-V and other new features in Windows 8 can be found on the [Explore page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hh771458) of the Springboard Series on TechNet.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `Virtualization Enabled in Firmware` read `No`, even though I had enabled it in my UEFI/BIOS settings.  It just wasn't taking effect at first.  As @Chaos mentioned, it was likely partially due to Windows' ability to save its kernel state.  I described the resolution process in another answer.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. What usually does the trick is to disable fast boot because it seems to check those kind of settings from the kernel state image.

Comment: That's probably why I had to retry it so many times.

Answer (score 1):

Having just experienced this issue myself today, I think the trick is to restart the computer and not shut down. I had done a few cold reboots with no success and went to disable the fast-boot option where I read the following:

"Turn on fast startup - This helps start your PC faster after shutdown. Restart isn't affected"

I then proceeded to restart the computer instead of shutdown and hey presto, it worked! This could be be coincidence but I think it's likely that fast startup is disabled in the event of a restart.